# Ionic 3 : All options get selected with radiogroup

Tags: ionic3, angular5

I am quite new to ionic and angular.I am trying to show dynamic ionic radio group like this :

```
<ion-slides slidesPerView="2" (ionSlideWillChange)="onSlideChanged()">
<ion-slide *ngFor="let session of sessionsDetails">
    <div class="sloatsdate" *ngIf="session.slots_remaining == 0 else showradiobutton">
        <div class="sloatsdate"><span class="font-size-13">Seats Full</span></div>
    </div>
    <ng-template #showradiobutton>
        <ion-list radio-group name="selectedslot" class="check1" #selectedslot="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="session.checked" [(ngModel)]="session.session_date" (ngModelChange)="checkboxselect(session.session_date)" [disabled]="session.slots_remaining == 0">
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>Select</ion-label>
                <ion-radio value="{{session.session_date}}"></ion-radio>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ng-template>
</ion-slide>
```

But I am getting an issue that all options are getting selected with radio-group.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to use a loop on ion-item : `<ion-item *ngFor="session of sessionsDetails">...</ion-item>`

Becouse in this case you create every loop a new radioGroup. So all of them will be selected

Comment: tried this solution also but still facing an issue.